# beamer's ignorenonframetext option and \AtEndDocument

Tags: beamer, pandoc

The following code example produce an error when compiling it with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\AtEndDocument{\begin{frame}{Last page}Last page\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test document}Test\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output of `pdflatex beamer_test.tex` (with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and a <kbd>x</kbd> as input to quit the compilation):

```
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2])
*^C! Interruption.
<*> 

? x
```

On the other hand, if I remove the `ignorenonframetext` option, everything works fine.

Now the issue is that in my real setting, the option gets produced by `pandoc` (using `pandoc -s -t beamer -o beamer_test.pdf -V theme:mytheme beamer_test.md`), and the `\AtEndDocument` command is in the outer part of `my_theme` (to mimick a powerpoint based theme with a fixed last page). I haven't found a `pandoc` option to get rid of the option.

For what is worse, here are a minimal markdown document and beamer theme that trigger the issue with the command line above:

`beamerthememytheme.sty`

```
\AtEndDocument{\begin{frame}{Last page}Last page\end{frame}}
```

`beamer_test.md`

```
# Test document

test
```

Is there a way to make `mytheme` work with `pandoc`, without removing `-s` and providing my own preamble (otherwise, I can as well stick with LaTeX all along)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore the ignore option, you could try to add `\beamer@ignorenonframefalse` in your `beamerthememytheme.sty` or

```
\makeatletter
\beamer@ignorenonframefalse
\makeatother
```

in the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\beamer@ignorenonframefalse
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{\begin{frame}{Last page}Last page\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test document}Test\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Just tested with `pandoc`. A `beamerthememytheme.sty` with

```
\beamer@ignorenonframefalse
\AtEndDocument{\begin{frame}{Last page}Last page\end{frame}}
```

seems to work and produces both the normal frame and the end frame.